# LDAP how to modify attribute _name_

Tags: ldap, ldif

I need to update for some thousand entries the name of an LDAP attribute, eg. 
`cn=myentry,ou=people,o=mycompany` has an attribute like `surname` and it shall be renamed to `lastname` and preserve the value.

Any clue how to achieve this with ldiff-commands?
Just to be clear I don't want to rename the rdn but the attribute name.

Answer (score 2):

1. Ensure that the new attribute name is in the schema
2. Export existing data
3. Change attribute names in exported LDIF
4. Import modified LDIF